# Losing foreach with Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I was wondering if I could replace this `foreach` with LINQ queries somehow (if possible):

Online playpen: https://ideone.com/PQEytf

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // dummy inputs for test sake
        var keys = new[] { "key1", "key2" };

        var services = new Dictionary<string, Service>
        {
            {"key1", new Service {Components = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"comp1", "value1"}}}},
            {"key2", new Service {Components = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"comp2", "value2"}}}}
        };


        var serviceComponents = GetServiceComponents(keys, services);
        // do something with it
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ServiceComponent> GetServiceComponents(string[] keys, Dictionary<string, Service> services)
    {
        var serviceComponents = new List<ServiceComponent>();

        // this is the foreach that I want to lose
        foreach (
            var key in
                keys.Select(
                    name =>
                        services.FirstOrDefault(
                            x => x.Key.Equals(name))))
        {
            serviceComponents.AddRange(key.Value.Components.Select(component => new ServiceComponent
            {
                Name = key.Key,
                Service = component.Key,
                Value = component.Value,
            }));
        }

        return serviceComponents.ToArray();

    }
}

public class Service
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Components { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceComponent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `SelectMany`, however, by using `FirstOrDefault` you're opening yourself up to a `NullReferenceException` (as the default value for any reference type is `null`). If you intend to have a `NullReferenceException` thrown when an element of `keys` is not a key in `services` then you can use other answers which leverage `SelectMany`. However, is you do not intend a `NullReferenceException`, then you should use something like the following:

```
return services.Where(pair => keys.Contains(pair.Key))
               .SelectMany(pair => 
                           pair.Value.Components
                                .Select(component => new ServiceComponent
                                                         {
                                                             Name = pair.Key,
                                                             Service = component.Key,
                                                             Value = component.Value
                                                          }))
               .ToArray();
```

This statement removes all key-value pairs from `services` whose key is not in the `keys` array, then turns each element of each pair's `Components` into a new `ServiceComponent` object, with the `SelectMany` making a single flat list out of the new `ServiceComponent`s.

Comment: I like the resiliency of this solution!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, what you're looking for is `SelectMany`.  That allows you to turn each item in the sequence into another sequence, and then flatten all of those sequences into a single sequence.  (You're accomplishing the same thing, without the deferred execution, by putting all of the sequences into a list.)

```
return keys.SelectMany(name => services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(name))
    .Value.Components
    .Select(component => new ServiceComponent
    {
        Name = name.Key,
        Service = component.Key,
        Value = component.Value,
    }))
    .ToArray();
```

Having said that, what this query is doing is taking each of your keys, finding the corresponding item in services *using a linear search*, and then mapping the result.  Rather than doing a linear search using `FirstOrDefault`, you can use the dictionary's native ability to effectively and efficiently find values for each key:

```
return keys.SelectMany(key => services[key].Components
    .Select(component => new ServiceComponent
    {
        Name = key,
        Service = component.Key,
        Value = component.Value,
    }))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I knew the answer would revolve around `SelectMany` but couldn't quite put my finger on it. Also, your second point about losing `FirstOrDefault` is icing on the cake! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To extend @Servy's example, I often find the LINQ expression syntax to be easier to read than the lambda SelectMany (it translates to the same thing). Here is his query using query expressions:

```
return from key in keys
       from component in services[key].Components
       select new ServiceComponent
       {
          Name = key,
          Service = component.Key,
          Value = component.Value,
       }))
       .ToArray();
```

Comment: That's not called LINQ syntax, that's *query syntax*.  LINQ is the name given to the methods in the `System.Linq` namespace.  Both solutions are using LINQ.

Comment: It is a Language Integrated Query (LINQ) syntax. This one with query expressions rather than lambda expressions.

Comment: [MSDN defines it as query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx), not LINQ syntax.  LINQ syntax is not a thing, at least not officially.  The other syntax is method syntax, not lambda syntax.  Both of which are two different syntaxes for writing a LINQ query.

Comment: Completely agree with readability, at least to people less experienced with lambdas/LINQ or people looking at this answer on their mobile devices! :)

Comment: And the C# specification (section 17.6) and [MSDN C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb397676(v=vs.99).aspx) refer to it as query expression. I chose to not say LINQ query expression here because "Language Intregated Query query expression" is a bit redundant. Not trying to get into a semantic debate. Just wanted to point out another alternative syntax regardless of what it is called.

Comment: query expressions are a tool used by query syntax.  query syntax is in effect the collection of all of the query expressions, in the same way that method syntax is composed of a series of method expressions.  It is specifically *not* LINQ query expressions because query expressions are not specific to LINQ.  Query expressions can be used entirely outside of the context of LINQ.  The syntax is not defined by the use of LINQ at all, calling it LINQ syntax is misleading.